# Not able to plot band structure in p4vasp

Tags: 14.04, plot

Not able to plot band structure in p4vasp.

Runtime error is:

```
vivek@vivek-Lenovo-Flex-2-14:~/apps$ p4v

(p4v.py:5002): libglade-WARNING **: Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(p4v.py:5002): libglade-WARNING **: Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(p4v.py:5002): libglade-WARNING **: Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/p4vasp/applet/GraphWindowApplet.py:266: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_set_events: assertion '!gtk_widget_get_realized (widget)' failed
  x.set_events(event_mask)
/usr/share/p4vasp/p4v.py:81: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_progress_set_percentage: assertion 'percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 1.0' failed
  self.progressbar.set_fraction(float(step)/float(total))

(p4v.py:5002): libglade-WARNING **: Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/p4vasp/p4v.py", line 642, in idle_func
    scheduler().next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/p4vasp/schedule.py", line 51, in next
    return self[0].next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/p4vasp/applet/ElectronicApplet.py", line 462, in updateEigenvaluesGen
    ly=len(ev[0][0])
TypeError: __len__() should return an int
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the missing file libgnome.so is provided by either      libgnomeui-0 or libgnomeui-0-dbg. To install libgnomeui-0 (GNOME user interface library - runtime files) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnomeui-0
```